# Load More Not working for amp-list in product listing page

Tags: amp-html

Here I am getting first 20 product details to display when the page loads and when show more button is clicked, I am fetching next 20 products and appending them to previous results.

In Mozilla Firefox browser, load more button is working fine on first time page load but when I reload the page, load more button is not working.

In chrome browser load more button is not working on first time page load but when I click on browser back button and forward button its working.

I am not getting any errors. I am unable to figure out what the problem is.

```
    <amp-state id="productsState" src="/solrSearchAmp?productCategoryId=14030181&sortResults=customerRating-desc"></amp-state>
<amp-state id="product">
    <script type="application/json">
        {
        "start":20,
        "hasMorePages": true
        }
    </script>
</amp-state>

<amp-list src="/solrSearchAmp?productCategoryId=14030181&sortResults=customerRating-desc" [src]="productsState.items" width="320" height="2000" [height]="productsState.items.length * 200" class="m1">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
    <li class="content navigation ampsiteHeaderNavigation">
        <div class="js_eCommerceThumbNailHolder eCommerceThumbNailHolder">
            <div class="js_swatchProduct">
                <a class="pdpUrl" title="{{name}}" href="{{seoFriendlyUrl}}" id="{{productId}}">
                    <amp-img alt="{{name}}" title="{{name}}" src="http&#58;&#47;&#47;{{productImageSmallUrl}}" class="productThumbnailImage"
                    height="140"
                    width="170">
                    </amp-img>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="content navigation ampsiteHeaderNavigation">
        {{#outOfStock}}
            <div class="stock">Out Of Stock</div>
        {{/outOfStock}}
        <div>
            <a class="eCommerceProductLink pdpUrl" title="{{name}}" href="{{seoFriendlyUrl}}" id="detailLink_{{productId}}"><span>{{name}}</span></a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="content navigation ampsiteHeaderNavigation">
        <div class="js_plpPriceList">
            <span><b>&#x20b9;{{listPrice}}</b></span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="content navigation ampsiteHeaderNavigation">
        <div class="js_plpPriceSavingPercent">
        {{#showPercent}}
            <span>({{youSavePercent}}% off)</span>
        {{/showPercent}}
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="content navigation ampsiteHeaderNavigation">
        <div class="js_plpPriceOnline">
            <span><b>&#x20b9;{{price}}</b></span>
        </div>
    </li>
    </template>
</amp-list>
<form method="GET" action="/solrSearchAmp?productCategoryId=14030181&sortResults=customerRating-desc"
    action-xhr="/solrSearchAmp?productCategoryId=14030181&sortResults=customerRating-desc"
    target="_top"
    on="submit-success: AMP.setState({
            productsState: {
            items: productsState.items.concat(event.response.items),
            },
            product:{
            start: product.start + 20,
            hasMorePages: event.response.hasMorePages
            }
        });">
    <input type="hidden" name="start" value="20" [value]="product.start">
    <input type="submit"
    value="Show more"
    class="ampstart-btn caps m1 show"
    [class] = "(product.hasMorePages == false ? 'hide' : 'ampstart-btn caps m1 mb3 show')">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure to always access the correct `start` value. It is initially defined as: `productsState.start`. However, in your form you set and access it via `product.start`.

If you append `#development=1` to the URL you can debug the current amp-state in the browser console via: `AMP.printState()`.

Comment: Hi I have checked as you said it's showing updated results like

Comment: {"product":{"start":10,"hasMorePages":true},"productsState":{"items":[{"id":"140301106_140316586_SGJ716_140301","productId":"140............but not displaying in ui